# Python: Autofill cells with formula in above cell, MAC OS

Tags: python, excel, macos

I am writing a python code in which I have an existing excel worksheet with
existing formulas that is written already from H4:5 and other formulas across the sheet up to Z4:Z5
I was wondering if there was a way to drag these formulas down to the last cell, for example row 100 
I found a way to do it on windows, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868410/python-autofill-cells-in-excel-according-to-a-formula-in-previous-cells)** , but the win32com package is not accessible through mac. 
Any guidance would be helpful, thanks

Comment: does the output have to be in XLS or in XLSX format, or are both OK?

Comment: both are okay @WalterTross

Answer (score 1):

I have not made spreadsheet programs on Mac, but I would recommend the openpyxl module at: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ for dealing with formulas within the sheet. If you would like to deal with the *result* of the formula then xlwings would be the better alternative at https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html
For instance if you're trying to copy =SUM(A3:A5) (I think you're doing something similar) you should use openpyxl. If you're trying to get the value of that addition (say its a float of 5.34) then you should use xlwings. I've had projects that use both as well, so it's something to consider...